# how can i solved this problem ([vite] Internal server error: Cannot redefine property: File)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, vite

I have a problem every time I use Vite with React. I don't know what the problem is, and I searched a lot, but I was unable to find a solution to it.

I tried a lot to change the version of Node and NPM but to no avail

```
➜  Local:   http://localhost:3000/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
Cannot redefine property: File
10:07:17 PM [vite] Internal server error: Cannot redefine property: File
  Plugin: vite:react-babel
  File: C:/Users/musta/Desktop/idurar-erp-crm-master/frontend/src/main.jsx
      at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\musta\Desktop\idurar-erp-crm-master\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\musta\Desktop\idurar-erp-crm-master\frontend\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\helpers\config-api.js:16:14)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: maybe this helps: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/14299

Comment: All that was suggested was changing the Node versions, and I did that, but to no avail

Comment: which version did you try? you need to be specific in what info you provide

Comment: I tried on several versions: 16.0.0, 18.0.0, and 20.10.0 latest version of node, also I use the latest version of vite.
As soon as I select React with JavaScript download the npm package and run the default project, this problem appears

Comment: hm, I would have expected 20.10.0 to work as the fix seems to be in 20.7.0

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be easily fixed by upgrading node to any version above 20.6.1.
It's preferred to upgrade to the LTS version.
Please refer to https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/14299 for more details